# Magento 2 : What is use of observableArray in JS file with knockout JS?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.2, knockoutjs, viewmodel

I have checked `observableArray` word declared in js file at top position.

I have been seen
this function like this `items: ko.observableArray([])`. Is this function related to AJAX while response is getting and pushing json data in object ? or is it useful when pageload ? PLEASE someone clear this concept about `observableArray`

How it can be useful this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ko.observableArray` is not much different from `ko.observable` , if you want to detect and respond to changes on one object, you’d use observables. If you want to detect and respond to changes of a collection of things, use an observableArray.

This function is not related to ajax directly in any way, it's use is same as obsevable with difference that it is used for arrays/ collection of items . But **if you want that the updated values of a array/json are sent after updating a viewModel then you will have to declare it as observable or it will just send initial values**.

Observable arrays are defined in the form of json objects as defined below ;

```
var observableArray = ko.observableArray([
    { name: "Bungle", type: "Bear" },
    { name: "George", type: "Hippo" },
    { name: "Zippy", type: "Unknown" }
]);
```

You can read up more about this here - http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html

Comment: To add to this: RTFM http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html